# Copying files from inside a Java project to an absolute path

Tags: java, file, package, copying

Simply, I have one package with all of my built code, and another (called "DummieClasses") with a number of files which need to be coped to a file location on command.  I've tried using:

```
File file1 = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile()+filename);
FileChannel srcChannel = new FileInputStream("/DummieClasses/yr.png").getChannel();
FileChannel dstChannel = new FileOutputStream(file1).getChannel();
dstChannel.transferFrom(srcChannel, 0, srcChannel.size());
```

...thinking that it would copy yr.png from the package DummieClasses to a chosen location, but so far, no luck.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'project' and 'inside your project'. Sitting in the file system? Packaged into a jar?

Comment: *"no luck"*  Programming does not depend on 'luck' & when it fails, we generally get verbose and detailed error information.  Where is the stack trace?  BTW - it won't work with `File` or `FileChannel` of the resource is in a Jar.  In that case, it must be accessed by `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 7, you can use [`Files.copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) to do this for you.